# Problem on linear differential equation of second order.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f(x)$ and $xf(x)$ be the particular solutions of the differential equation $y'' + R(x)y' + S(x)y = 0$ then the solution of the differential equation  $y'' + R(x)y' + S(x)y = f(x)$ is

$A).$ $ (-\frac{x^{2}}{2} + ax + b)f(x)$

$B).$ $ (\frac{x^{2}}{2} + ax + b)f(x)$

$C)$. $ (-x^{2}+ ax + b)f(x)$

$D)$. $ (\frac{x^{2}}{2} -ax + b)f(x)$

I could only find one solution by variation of parameters method, which is $\frac{x^{2}}{2} f(x)$

Is there any way to solve this problem without putting these options in given differential equation to check if these satisfy the equation$?$

Comment: Because the equation is linear and $f(x)$ and $xf(x)$ are solutions of the homogeneous equation, then when you substitute any of those, the terms $\pm axf(x)$ and $bf(x)$ get cancelled. So, all that matters is what happens with the term $\pm\frac{x^2}{2}f(x)$.

Comment: So $b$ and $d$ are true and $a,c$ are false.

Comment: If you got that $\frac{x^2}{2}f(x)$ satisfies the equation and $-\frac{x^2}{2}f(x)$ doesn't then yes. I haven't made any computations myself.

Comment: I have only got that $x^{2}/2$ satisfies the equation. I didn't check for $-x^{2}/2$. But $-x^{2}/2$ should give $-f(x)$ and $-x^{2}$, $-2f(x)$

Comment: Note that you don't really need to substitute $-\frac{x^2}{2}f(x)$. Because the equation is linear, if substituting $G(x)$ in the differential operator gives you $H(x)$, then substituting $aG(x)$, for a constant $a$, should give you $aH(x)$. So, if substituting $\frac{x^2}{2}f(x)$ gives you $f(x)$, then substituting $-\frac{x^2}{2}f(x)$ will give you $-f(x)$.

Comment: Okay @MoonLightSyzygy, thanks :)